# How can bitwise operations be modeled with math?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In programming, if I did `100 | 001` (`|` being the "or" operator), I would get `101`. Can this be done in math? I.e. with sets:
$$A=\{1,0,0\}$$ 
$$B=\{0,0,1\}$$
$$A ?B = \{1,0,1\}$$
Is there an  operator that would satisfy the equation in place of the question mark? Thanks.

Comment: "or" can be represented by the "max" function

Comment: Sets are not the appropriate structure for this. In a set, order doesn't matter, and repeated elements are removed, so $\{1,0,0\}=\{0,0,1\}=\{0,1\}$. Instead, use ordered $n$-tuples, like $(1,0,0)$.

Comment: This is a bit different with sets, because for your boolean operation the orders matters, while for sets the order in which elements are listed does not matter.  You would have to construct a specific space where the order matters for this to work.

Comment: Do you know the "logic" thing? They use ^ for and ∨ for or, but that's not math.

Comment: He could use vectors instead, right?

Comment: @MCCCS: "that's not math": are you serious ?

Comment: @Théophile which binary operation could be used on tuples?

Comment: I think $(1, 0, 0)∨(0, 0, 1) ≡ (1, 0, 1)$ is the best choice. And @YvesDaoust I thought logic is a seperate thing from math.

Comment: @MCCCS "but that's not math" [That's news to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic).

Comment: @Noah: I guess you missed it, [but logic and set theory are not mathematics at all...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303723/what-is-the-difference-between-set-theory-and-taxonomy) :P

Comment: This question, however, is definitely not a question about set theory. And it would be wise to read the tag excerpt before blindly picking tags for your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila since I don't know which area of math is applicable and that's part of my question, I chose the tag the described how I thought about this intuitively.

Comment: In fact, $A$ and $B$ can both be non-negative integers,
and you can define bitwise OR and bitwise AND operations.
There are examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576796/formulating-the-bitwise-or-operation) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/expressing-bitwise-operations-in-terms-of-other-functions).

Comment: Archie, I figured that much. And I pointed out that there are explanations to these tags which explain to you when and how to use them. Not knowing where the nearest public restroom is located is not a valid excuse for pissing on someone else's door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AND and OR operators can be modelled algebraically thus:
$$
\begin{align}
a \wedge b &= ab\\
a \vee b &= a+b-ab
\end{align}$$

Now, for $A,B \in \Bbb Z_2^n$, that is, $A=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ where $a_i,b_i \in \{0,1\}$, define
$$
\begin{align}
A \wedge B &= (a_1\wedge b_1,\ldots,a_n\wedge b_n)\\
A \vee B &= (a_1\vee b_1,\ldots,a_n\vee b_n)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice way to model this mathematically. Let's represent each number in binary as a set of positions. More formally, construct an injection $f:\mathbb{N\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})}$ as follows: for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$
$$x=2^{a_n}+2^{a_{n - 1}}+\dots+2^{a_0}\mapsto \{a_n,a_{n-1},\dots,a_0 \}$$
or
$$f(x)=\{a_n,a_{n-1}, \dots,a_0\}$$
where $a_n>a_{n-1}>\dots>a_0$ and $a_n,a_{n-1},\dots,a_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. (This is just another way to say a number is the set of positions of bits in binary, e.g. $5_{10}=101_2\mapsto\{2,0\}$ and $7_{10}=111_2\mapsto \{2,1,0\}$. This assumes the fact that every natural number can be written as a sum of distinct powers of 2.)

If we use the same notation as programming ($|$ for bitwise OR and $\&$ for bitwise AND),

As an exercise, you can try to prove that $f(x|y)=f(x)\cup f(y)$ and $f(x \, \& \, y) = f(x) \cap f(y)$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, writing $\{0,0,1\}$ is not what you *really* want. Because sets ignore repetition and order, that would be the same as $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0\}$ or $\{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1\}$.

What you want is to think about sequences, binary sequences. However, you can also think about sets directly.

Say you only care about sequences of length $n$, this will simplify things a bit, then you can think about subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. If $A$ is a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then $k\in A$ if and only if the $k$th indexed bit in the sequence that $A$ represent equals to $1$.

For example with $n=3$, then $\{1,2,3\}$ would be the sequence $(1,1,1)$ and $\{2\}$ would be $(0,1,0)$.

Now we get that $A\cup B$ is the bitwise or operator, $A\cap B$ is the bitwise and operator, and symmetric difference $A\mathbin{\triangle}B$ is the bitwise xor operator.

Comment: It feels good to know that I feel awkward starting the indexing from $1$ and not from $0$.